# Ansible: core modules are missing

Tags: debian, ansible

I willing to get a list of variables for the host using `ansible all -m system` and keep getting an error:

> The module system was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing. If this is a checkout, run 'git pull --rebase' to correct this problem.

What is the default directory for the module files?

Answer (score 1):

Listing variables for a host would be done using the `setup` module:

```
$ ansible -m setup 127.0.0.1
127.0.0.1 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "ansible_all_ipv4_addresses": [
            "10.255.42.178", 
            "10.255.0.1"
        ], 
...
```

Note there is no module named system: [system](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/list_of_system_modules.html) is a group of Ansible modules.